# Sencha touch 2.3.0 form panel send the text value of combobox and not the id value when for is submied

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch form which has multiple combo boxes,but when i submit the formpanel the display field value is send in the request instead of the  value field. I am using sencha touch 2.3.0.

```
        this.getDetailsPanel().submit({
            url: 'savedetails.php',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function() {
                alert('form submitted successfully!');
            },
            failure:function(){
                alert("connection error");
            }
        });
}
```

any pointers ..? combo box used in the form is given bellow

```
 {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: 'assignedToDepartment',
                    label: 'Assigned to Department',
                    options:[
                             {text:'All',value:'0'},
                             {text:'Daniel Craig',value:'1'},
                             {text:'Sean Connery',value:'2'}
                             ]
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `displayField` and `valueField` configuration in [selectfield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-valueField).

**Like this**

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    name: 'assignedToDepartment',
    label: 'Assigned to Department',
    displayField : 'text',
    valueField : 'value',
    options:[
      {text:'All',value:'0'},
      {text:'Daniel Craig',value:'1'},
      {text:'Sean Connery',value:'2'}
   ]
},
```